# solidity: how can i call a payable function from another contract and enter the amount i want to pay? the other contract is not on the editor

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IBank {
    function addTax(uint256 moneyToAdd) external payable;
   
    
}

contract Counter {
    uint public count;
    address bankAddress;

    function setbankAddress(address _bankAddress) public payable {
       bankAddress = _bankAddress;
    }

    function addMon(uint moneyToAdd) public payable {
        require(moneyToAdd <= msg.value, "Ether value sent is not 
        correct");
        
    }
    function pay(uint _Amount) public payable {
        IBank(bankAddress).addTax{value:_Amount}(_Amount);
 
    }
}
```

when I deploy it I first add the contract address that I want to interact with, it's working with all functions that do not require value

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you using Remix? If yes, did you add the value in the parameters? There is a field called "Value" over the field with your contract name in the left sidebar.

Comment: I won't flag this as duplicate because it was asked on ethereum.stackexchange, but here's a link to the same question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/how-can-you-call-a-payable-function-in-another-contract-with-arguments-and-send